# CSS Postions Element

Tags: css, html

Small and Easy question. I got these CSS rules.

```
html {
    background-image:url('../images/background1.jpg');
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

body {
    font-family:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
    border:  3px solid rgb(75,75,75);
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px 5px rgba(40,80,100,.75);
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomrightt: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background:url('../images/background4.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 900px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Now I just want to add in the sides, not in body, but relative postioned advertisment boxs... how do I do that?
thanks ahead

Comment: All the visible content on a web page is in the body.  It's not clear what you mean by "sides, not in body".  It might help if you could provide an image of what you want.

Comment: I notice when I edit html rules in css.. I got the % that isn't in the 960px of the body, now outside of the 960px rage, I want to add advertisment boxs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want extra content to the sides of the body, what you'll need to do is to specify 3 `<div>` elements, set them each to a width of the page (if you want adverts each side of a main area you can either set percentages for each div to take up using the css width property or you can set it in pixels if you want exact measurements.

Have the second "middle" div as your new "body" where you will have your content.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have everything in your body. If you are trying to achieve a 3 column structure with the middle as what the body currently is and 2 places on the side you can do something like.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
</div>
```

and in your CSS replace body with #main adding another 2 properties `float: left; width: 70%`

also add css properties for your other elements

```
#wrapper {width: 100%;}
#left {width: 15%; float: left;}
#right {width: 15%;float:left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I think you want it uses `html` and `css`

http://jsfiddle.net/Hive7/tzeTQ/1/